# ListView scrolling issue in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I have an activity, which hosts several fragments. This activity layout also contains a footer. One of the fragments has a ListView, which needs to be scrollable, as the last item appears behind the footer of the activity layout. The matter is that I wasn't able to make it scrollable. Here're my layouts:

Activity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container">
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/footer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#384554"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_resources"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
    app:theme="@style/MyNavigationDrawer"/>

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My fragment:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/fragment_activities_catalogue">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/city_picture"
    android:src="@drawable/city_header"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#c4c4c4"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true">

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question what i understood is that your footer hides the last item of your list view ....

for this you can modify your layout like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="0.85"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                layout="@layout/extra_tool"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_weight="0.80"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container">
            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <include
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            layout="@layout/extra_tool"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#384554"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first LinearLayout is "match_parent" so the footer is behind or before.

Give the LinearLayout an id("...topComponent...") and put the layout-attribute "layout_below="...topComponent..." to the footer include.

You have to try abit how to layout proper but the RelativeLAyout parent gives you all what you need. With the designer view you can check, how to put the attributes correct since you can see what happens directly.

Play with the layout attributes of the LinearLayout and the footer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using DrawerLayout which by defaults receives all the touches, In 
**public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item){},**  function return false in end instead of true.
Try if that works.